# tr1::function and tr1::bind

Tags: c++, tr1

I put the following into Ideone.com (and codepad.org):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tr1/functional>
 
struct A {
    A(const std::string& n) : name_(n) {}
    void printit(const std::string& s) 
    {
        std::cout << name_ << " says " << s << std::endl;
    }
private:
    const std::string name_;
};
 
int main()
{
    A a("Joe");
    std::tr1::function<void(const std::string&)> f = std::tr1::bind(&A::printit, &a, _1);
    a("Hi");
}
```

And got these errors:

> prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>
> prog.cpp:18: error: ‘_1’ was not declared in this scope
>
> prog.cpp:19: error: no match for call to ‘(A)(const char [3])’
>
> prog.cpp:18: warning: unused variable ‘f’

I can't for the life of me figure out what's wrong on line 18.

Comment: Try `std::tr1::placeholders::_1`.

Comment: Need a tr1:: in there too.  I think I only recently made tr1 placeholders and c++11 placeholders compatible with each other

Comment: @JonathanWakely, Oops, never used the tr1 ones. I forgot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two errors:

1. `_1` is defined within the namespace `std::tr1::placeholders`. You need to either `using namespace std::tr1::placeholders;` **within `main()`**, or use `std::tr1::placeholders::_1`.
2. Line 19 should be `f("Hi")`, not `a("Hi")`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tr1/functional>

struct A {
    A(const std::string& n) : name_(n) {}
    void printit(const std::string& s) 
    {
        std::cout << name_ << " says " << s << std::endl;
    }
private:
    const std::string name_;
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std::tr1::placeholders;  // <-------

    A a("Joe");
    std::tr1::function<void(const std::string&)> f = std::tr1::bind(&A::printit, &a, _1);
    f("Hi");    // <---------
}
```

Comment: Emphasis on the **within main()**.

Answer (score 5):

You get `prog.cpp:18: error: ‘_1’ was not declared in this scope` because `_1` is in the namespace `std::tr1::placeholders`, so you need to use`std::tr1::placeholders::_1` or a `using namespace std::tr1::placeholders`.

`prog.cpp:19: error: no match for call to ‘(A)(const char [3])’` comes from the fact that you try to call `a("Hi")` when it should be `f("Hi")`

The [fixed code](http://ideone.com/lHSlV) compiles just fine.